# Ajax is not working in android phone using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, phonegap

"it always alert failure but in case of browser its working fine nor its send data to ajax url "

```
jQuery.ajax({
          url:'http://182.18.164.87/jd/action.php?action=register',
          crossDomain: true,
          type: 'POST',  
          data: data,
          contentType: "application/json",  
          dataType: 'jsonp',  
          jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
          timeout: 5000,
          success: function(data,status){

                    alert('success');
                    localStorage.clear();



               return true;
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure')
            return false;
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to whitelist the URL host (i.e. http://182.18.164.87/) in your config.xml, otherwise it will be blocked for security reason:

```
<access origin="http://182.18.164.87" />
```

You will need the whitelist plugin too.

Comment: Thanks by using this line in <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" /> in config.xml it works.

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
  $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://182.18.164.87/jd/action.php",
                         data: {"data":val},
                         cache: false,
                         async:false,
                         success: function(data){ 

                             var data = JSON.parse(data);   
                             alert('success');
                              localStorage.clear();

                            },
                            error: function(){
                                 alert('failure')
                               return false;
                            }
                        });
```